# Program that reads file with numbers

Tags: c#

I am working on a program that read the file with car model and fuel consumption.

In file I have cars like A|12.45, where A stand for model and number stands for fuel consumption per 100Km. Every car is in it's own line.

File looks like that:

A|8.11

B|14.38

C|13.05

Here we can see that B has highest consumption but when I run that program in console it shows up as 1438 L without dot in the middle. How can I fix this?

I have a code that looks like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        StreamReader readF = File.OpenText(@"D:\CarList.txt");
        string line = readF.ReadLine();

        double highest = 0;
        double lowest = 300;

        string nameHighest= "";
        string nameLowest= "";

        while (line != null)
        {

            string[] temp = line.Split('|');


            if (Convert.ToDouble(temp[1]) > highest)
            {
                highest= Convert.ToDouble(temp[1]);
                nameHighest = temp[0];
            }


            if (Convert.ToDouble(temp[1]) < lowest)
            {

                lowest = Convert.ToDouble(temp[1]);
                nameLowest = temp[0];
            }

            line = readF.ReadLine();
        }
        readF.Close();


        Console.WriteLine("Highest consumption: " + nameHighest + ". It consumes " + highest + " L per 100Km.");
        Console.WriteLine("Lowest consumption " + nameLowest + ". It consumes " + lowest + " L per 100Km");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code you've given won't compile due to typos, which suggests it's not the *actual* code that gives the wrong result. Please provide a short but complete program that you've compiled yourself, along with the expected output and the actual output. (I'd also suggest using `File.ReadLines` to make things much simpler...)

Comment: That code doesn't do what you say. Either the decimal point is being stripped on reading the file and parsing the number, or it's being formatted incorrectly when written to the console, or it's not in the file in the first place. Use the debugger and find out.

Comment: In future, please make it *complete* - including class declaration, using directives etc, and try to cut out pointless whitespace (e.g. at the start of the while loop, and the double blank lines in various places). However, this code works for me with the input you've shown. It may be a culture issue - what's the culture (region) on the machine you're running this on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect this is because the default culture on your machine is one that uses `,` instead of `.` for a decimal separator. You can use `double.Parse` and specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to parse it using the invariant culture which *does* use `.` for the separator.

I would actually rewrite your code in several steps.

Step 1: use `double.Parse`, and only do so once per line - likewise extract `temp[0]` once per line.

Step 2: use `double.NegativeInfinity` as the initial "highest" and `double.PositiveInfinity` as the initial "lowest", so that *any* finite entry will register.

Step 3: use a format string at the end. With C# 6 we can use string interpolation, but at least we can make it simpler than it is before then.

Step 4: use `File.ReadLines` instead of reading them "manually"

At this point we have:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double highest = double.NegativeInfinity;
        double lowest = double.PositiveInfinity;

        string nameHighest= "";
        string nameLowest= "";

        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("test.txt"))
        {
            string[] temp = line.Split('|');
            string name = temp[0];
            double consumption = double.Parse(
                temp[1],
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            if (consumption > highest)
            {
                highest = consumption;
                nameHighest = name;
            }

            if (consumption < lowest)
            {
                lowest = consumption;
                nameLowest = name;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(
            "Highest consumption: {0}. It conumes {1}L per 100km",
            nameHighest, highest);
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Lowest consumption: {0}. It conumes {1}L per 100km",
            nameLowest, lowest);
    }
}
```

Step 5: use LINQ to separate the reading and parsing of the data from the using it - although I'm storing everything in a list so we can go through it twice in a minute...

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cars = File.ReadLines("test.txt")
            .Select(line => line.Split('|'))
            .Select(bits => new { Name = bits[0], Consumption = double.Parse(bits[1]) })
            .ToList();

        if (cars.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No cars!");
            return;
        }

        var highest = cars[0];
        var lowest = cars[0];

        foreach (var car in cars.Skip(1))
        {
            if (car.Consumption > highest.Consumption)
            {
                highest = car;
            }

            if (car.Consumption < lowest.Consumption)
            {
                lowest = car;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(
            "Highest consumption: {0}. It consumes {1}L per 100km",
            highest.Name, highest.Consumption);
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Lowest consumption: {0}. It consumes {1}L per 100km",
            lowest.Name, lowest.Consumption);
    }
}
```

Step 6: Use [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/)'s `MinBy` and `MaxBy` to make it really simple:

```
using MoreLinq;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cars = File.ReadLines("test.txt")
            .Select(line => line.Split('|'))
            .Select(bits => new { Name = bits[0], Consumption = double.Parse(bits[1]) })
            .ToList();

        if (cars.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No cars!");
            return;
        }

        var highest = cars.MaxBy(c => c.Consumption);
        var lowest = cars.MinBy(c => c.Consumption);

        Console.WriteLine(
            "Highest consumption: {0}. It consumes {1}L per 100km",
            highest.Name, highest.Consumption);
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Lowest consumption: {0}. It consumes {1}L per 100km",
            lowest.Name, lowest.Consumption);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't even think of that. I replaced the . with , and now everything works as it should! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at these suggestions. Also, is there any simple way to do average consumption with these numbers? I can't figure it out how to make it. I know that it is (A value + B value + C value) / cars.Count, but when working with files like this I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Danes510: LINQ makes that fairly easily - if you don't know about it already I suggest you look it up :)